# Getting a list of Components (filtered) BasedOnSchema from Folder

Tags: templating, schema, componentpresentation

[Tridion beginner]

I have a folder named `Components` where I store different Components. Now, I would like (in C# code fragment template building block that I put in component template) to get list of components from this folder, based on certain schema, and put them in package, so I can later render them from DWT template building block.

This is what I have:

```
<%@Import Namespace="Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement"%>


  // run template with article component, so that article schema is processed

  string componentID = package.GetValue("Component.ID");
  Component articleComponent = (Component)engine.GetSession().GetObject(componentID);

  // Get the Schema of articleComponent
  Schema articleSchema = articleComponent.Schema;

  // get the folder of current component
  Folder componentsFolder = (Folder) articleComponent.OrganizationalItem;

  // Create a object of class Filter to filter retrieved content items.
  Filter filter = new Filter();

  // Filter out all items that are not based on the Schema called articleSchema.
  filter.Conditions["BasedOnSchema"] = articleSchema.Id;

  // Make the call to GetListItems() using this Filter object. For each item, the default set of items is returned.
  XmlElement listOfComponents = componentsFolder.GetListItems(filter );

  package.PushItem("listOfComponents", package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text,  listOfComponents.ToString()));
```

I have pushed XmlElement as String in package so I could see what am I getting, but all I get is just one line - "XmlElement". What am I doing wrong with reading components from folder, because there are couple components with appropriate schema in this folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the definition of XmlElement instead of the values contained in it.
Probably you can convert the XmlElement in to XmlDocment and retrieve the results .
Below is the syntax

```
        XmlDocument testDocument = new XmlDocument();
        testDocument = listOfComponents.OwnerDocument;
        package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateXmlDocumentItem(ContentType.Xml, testDocument ));
```

If you need the output to be in string then use below

```
        package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, listOfComponents.InnerXml.ToString())
```

Also note the method GetListItems(filter) is depreciated.

Comment: Thanks for help. Another possible solution could be using `GetItems()` method: `List<TcmUri> listOfComponents = new List<TcmUri>(); 

      foreach (Component c in componentsFolder.GetItems(filter))
      {
        listOfComponents.Add(c.Id);
      }`